# setAdapter doesn't work for a list inside a dialog

Tags: android-studio, android-listview

I am using this layout to render a dialog

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="ThemeDialog"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/AddToDictionary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="Add" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/declineButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Confirm" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eraseButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Erase" />
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code in my method to display list of items in an ordinary activity that works very well, but I try to display the same list in a list added to the dialog and this doesn't work although the debugger shows that the reference **dialog_suggestions_list_view** isn't null neither the **array** (my arrayAdapter), I need your help to point out where is the problem here, why setAdapter doesn't work with lists in dialogs?

```
   dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                    // Include dialog.xml file
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);


                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                    dialog_suggestions_list_view=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2) ;

                    if(dialog_suggestions_list_view!=null){
                        dialog_suggestions_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                String selectedFromList = (String)(dialog_suggestions_list_view.getItemAtPosition(position));
                                AppCompatEditText fContent = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.et_content);
                                fContent.append(selectedFromList);
                                fContent.append(" ");
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        Log.i("test","my list not found");
                    }

  ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add("Tic");
    array.add("Tac");
    array.add("Toe");
    
    ArrayAdapter < String > arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

    //display listView in ordianr activity
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    //display listView in dialog
    if(dialog_suggestions_list_view!=null){
        dialog_suggestions_list_view.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }else{
        Log.i("test","my list not found");
    }
```

Comment: `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);` – That is telling the `Dialog` that you want it to handle inflating the layout itself internally. The separate instance that you're inflating and setting the `ListView` up in is not the one that you see on-screen. You can either set your inflated `view` as the `Dialog` content instead, or call `findViewById()` on the `Dialog` itself.

Comment: I am using setContent() to include layouts of dialog.xml file, then I am using the inflater to have access via fidnViewById(), because when I get contented with just setContent() I found in the debugger that  dialog_suggestions_list_view is null.  Regarding your second remark that was just a typo, in my code I am referencing the same layout R.layout.dialog

Comment: Yeah, but those are two separate, unrelated instances. Layouts are just blueprints. They make no connection between the `View`s that are created from them at runtime. Your code currently has two different runtime `ListView` objects: the one that the `Dialog` is creating internally when it inflates that layout itself, and the separate one that you inflated. The only one you see, though, is the one that the `Dialog` made, but you never set your `Adapter` on that one.

Comment: Oh, there's this, too: `dialog_suggestions_list_view=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2) ;`. You need to call `findViewById()` on the `view` you just inflated, not on the `Activity`.

Comment: Looks like Suehtam has it all wrapped up into a proper example below.

Comment: Yes, I got your valuable notes. as you pointed out I was using setAdapter() on a listView that wasn't displayed in the dialog but it was another instance of the layout . thank you @MikeM. for your valuable remarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite confused with your code because it's missing some parts, but i did this see if helps.

```
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog), null);
    
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog_suggestions_list_view = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    dialog_suggestions_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {
                String selectedFromList = (String)(dialog_suggestions_list_view.getItemAtPosition(position));
                AppCompatEditText fContent = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.et_content);
                fContent.append(selectedFromList);
                fContent.append(" ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("test","my list not found");
            }
                
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<String> getList(){
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add("Tic");
    array.add("Tac");
    array.add("Toe");
    return array;
}
  
public void setInitialContentValue(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getList());

    //display listView in ordianr activity
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    //display listView in dialog
    try {
        dialog_suggestions_list_view.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("test","my list not found");
    }
}
```